# Design pattern to avoid extra method parameters when using one "catch all" setter or getter?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a (relatively) simple Java application in mind. A class MyReader will read data in from a config file and store it MyDataStore. Later on, another class MyBuilderClass will access the data in the store and builds a List of objects composed of a set of other classes Test1, Test2 etc. The exact composition of the List depends on the config read in.

I want to avoid having separate methods for each operation on MyDataStore, eg. setVar1(data), setVar2(data), readVar1(), readVar2() etc. Is there a relatively simple Design Pattern for this? The only thing I can think of right now is to pass a parameter in with the method like setVar(TestType.Test1, data), where TestType might be an Enum, for example, of the types Test1 etc.

Am I forgetting an easy pattern here?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about simple, but you seem to be describing a [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Comment: Why does it bother you to have many getters/setters? you can use Properties (map) to load, store and maintain all the config but the fact that less code is written doesn't necessarily mean that it'll be easier to dive into or maintain.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know if there is a design pattern for that, but you’re describing the behavior of a `Map`, which already have many implementations in java. If you use enums as keys, you can use an `EnumMap`.